# Mulesoft condense array of nested objects to single array of objects

Tags: json, dataweave, mulesoft, anypoint-studio, anypoint-platform

I have a dataset that is an array of objects, and each object is another object with an array inside of it. I am trying to flatten everything to a single array of the innermost objects, without the keys of the middle layer objects. I have tried to use the pluck functionality, but I cannot seem to get to what I am after. Example below.

Input:

```
[
  {
    "1234": [
      {
        "store": "07",
        "category": "1234",
        "account": "987"
      },
      {
        "store": "07",
        "category": "1234",
        "account": "555"
      },
      {
        "store": "07",
        "category": "1234",
        "account": "555"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "567": [
      {
        "store": "07",
        "category": "567",
        "account": "987"
      },
      {
        "store": "07",
        "category": "567",
        "account": "555"
      },
      {
        "store": "07",
        "category": "567",
        "account": "555"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Output:

```
[
      {
        "store": "07",
        "category": "1234",
        "account": "987"
      },
      {
        "store": "07",
        "category": "1234",
        "account": "555"
      },
      {
        "store": "07",
        "category": "1234",
        "account": "555"
      },
      {
        "store": "07",
        "category": "567",
        "account": "987"
      },
      {
        "store": "07",
        "category": "567",
        "account": "555"
      },
      {
        "store": "07",
        "category": "567",
        "account": "555"
      }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to iterate using `map`.
2. Convert object with key to array using `pluck`.
3. Covnert Nested array to 2d array using `flatten`.
4. Convert 2d array to 1d array using  `Reduce`

DW

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
flatten(payload map ($ pluck $)) reduce ($$++$)
```

Output

```
[
  {
    "store": "07",
    "category": "1234",
    "account": "987"
  },
  {
    "store": "07",
    "category": "1234",
    "account": "555"
  },
  {
    "store": "07",
    "category": "1234",
    "account": "555"
  },
  {
    "store": "07",
    "category": "567",
    "account": "987"
  },
  {
    "store": "07",
    "category": "567",
    "account": "555"
  },
  {
    "store": "07",
    "category": "567",
    "account": "555"
  }
]
```

Answer (score -1):

Below is one way of doing it. May be there is better way than this.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
flatten(payload map ($ pluck $)) reduce ((val, acc) -> acc ++ val)
```